# bootstrap 's pagination with angularjs could not click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am new to Angularjs.  I have created a pagination system, but when I ran my project, I couldn't click in it.  Here's a screenshot of my problem:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBFo8g2Vqhdc0EzbHRWZy1kdmc/view?usp=sharing

And here's the error code:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'track' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [pages track by $index] starting at [track by $index].
    at Error (native)
```

Here is my code in Javascript:

```
app.controller("listcontroller", function ($scope, listservice, $timeout) {
    listservice.getLophoc().then(function (data) {
        $scope.Lophoc = data;
        $scope.filteredTodos = [];
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.numPerPage = 1;
        $scope.maxSize = 2;;
        $scope.numPages = function () {
            return Math.ceil(data.length / $scope.numPerPage);
        };
        $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
            , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

            $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.Lophoc.slice(begin, end);
        });
    });
}
);
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Mã lớp</th>
            <th>Tên lớp</th>
            <th>Mã Gv</th>
            <th>sỉ số</th>
            <th>Mã Lớp trưởng</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in Lophoc">
            <td>{{ item.Malop }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Tenlop }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.MaGv}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Siso }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.Loptruong }}</td>

            <td>
                <a href="/Lophoc/edit/{{item.Malop}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/Lophoc/delete/{{item.Malop}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>                  
    </table>
    <pagination ng-model="currentPage"
                total-items="Lophoc.length"
                max-size="maxSize"
                boundary-links="true">
    </pagination>
</div>
```

I also added bootstrap libraries to my project.

Comment: I think you are missing some code here, can you paste the code where you are using `track by $index`?

Comment: I dont understand what is "track by $ index", I guess it in a javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `href="/Lophoc/edit/{{item.Malop}}"`

To: `ng-href="/Lophoc/edit/{{item.Malop}}"`